# Can we accomplish type level "Scrap Your Boilerplate" with open type families?

Tags: haskell, types, type-families

Is it possible to define a total type family open to refinements? Or, can we have "scrap your boilerplate" (and a little bit more) at the type level?

What I mean by this is a type family which has as it's base case

```
type family F a
type instance F a = a
```

but which allows refinement

```
-- later
type instance F X = Y
```

This is obviously overlapping and overlapping type families are disallowed for type safety. The nice property of this, however, is that `F` could apply over arbitrary types ignoring most of them and only "firing" against certain redexes.

There may be no direct answer. In that case, here is the use case I have. Perhaps there is a different answer possible.

I'd like to make a function for Servant which transforms API declarations. For those unfamiliar with Servant API declarations, they're a type constructed under something like the following rules (but open to extension by new rules)

```
x is a Symbol       |- Seg x is an API     (representing a static segment in the URI)
m is a Symbol       |- Capture m is an API (capturing data from the URI)
m is a Symbol       |- Header m is an API  (pulling in header info)
x and y are APIs    |- x :<|> y is an API  (biased choice)
x and y are APIs    |- x :> y is an API    (segment concatenation)
m is an HTTP method |- Verb m is an API    (endpoint, leaf)
```

This is a bit of a loosely typed tree and could be made more specific, but you get the idea.

```
Header "X-API-Version" :> "users" :> Capture "id" :> 
  (     Verb GET
   :<|> Verb POST
   :<|> Verb DELETE )
```

I'd like to extend this API tree with the following rules

```
 |- OptionsStub is an API
 ms is a list of Symbols |- Options ms is an API
```

where `Options ms` is an endpoint for `OPTIONS` which reports the CORS header `Access-Control-Allowed-Headers` describing the set of all request headers allowed for use at this endpoint. Given a tree which contains some `OptionsStub` endpoints within it, I can presumably push the `Header`s I see down the tree and replace `OptionsStub` types with `Options` types.

```
Header "If-Range" :> 
Seg "users" :> 
(      OptionsStub 
  :<|> Verb Get 
  :<|> Capture "id" ( OptionsStub :<|> Verb Get ) )
```

becomes

```
Header "If-Range" :> 
Seg "users" :> 
(      Options ["If-Range"]
  :<|> Verb Get 
  :<|> Capture "id" ( Options ["If-Range"] :<|> Verb Get ) )
```

enabling local reasoning around demonstration of `Options`.

```
type family Push hdrs api

-- interesting rules
type instance Push hdrs OptionsStub = Options hdrs
type instance Push hdrs (a :> b) = a :> Push (Pull a ++ hdrs) b

-- boring, but for completeness
type instance Push hdrs (Verb x) = Verb x
type instance Push hdrs (Seg s) = Seg s
type instance Push hdrs (Capture m) = Capture m
type instance Push hdrs (Header m) = Header m
type instance Push hdrs (x :<|> y) = Push hdrs x :<|> Push hdrs y

type family Pull api :: [*]

type instance Pull (Header m) = '[m]
type instance Pull a = '[]  -- OVERLAPPING
```

Crucially, I can define `Push` by doing complete analysis of the types that valid APIs are made of, but I decided not to do that for `Pull` and therefore am stuck with an overlapping instance.

More realistically, the overlapping instance is desirable because APIs are, as a kind, open to extension (or really, they're monokinded, but that has the same effect in practice) and yet my `Header` collection system is fixed. Presumably, nobody will ever extend API types with a new way of representing request headers (one already exists!) so my code may as well be closed for extension.

But if I use closed type families then, like this problem, type elaboration would get stuck.

I'd prefer to specify my type families simply

```
type instance Push hdrs OptionsStub = Options hdrs
type instance Push hdrs (a :> b) = a :> Push (Pull a ++ hdrs) b

type instance Pull (Header m) = '[m]
type instance Pull a = '[]
```

and then allow users to extend their API description rules without needing to extend the coverage of these type families.

Is there any mechanism to achieve this sort of end? Am I crazy to want it?

Comment: You are probably crazy to want it, but then again I think overlapping instances (and related tricks with closed type families) are very suspicious.

Comment: What goes wrong if you simply omit the clause `type instance Pull a = '[]`? (You haven't talked much about how `Pull` is used!)

Comment: Can you distinguish the different APIs by kind? If so, you could write `type family Pull (x :: k) :: [*]; type instance Pull (x :: SomeAPIKind) = SomeClosedTypeFamily x`, which gives you the full power of a closed type family but still allows the user to always extend the `Pull` type family by defining their own kind of API with data kinds.

Comment: @DanielWagner I added an example which I hopes help to justify the question. If the pull clause is omitted then the type family will get stuck and litter the API tree with `Pull` clauses that have no meaning. I'd like it just to be, essentially, a kind morphism. Except that both kinds are (a) not represented in the system and (b) "open".

Comment: @user2407038 I didn't realize that worked! It won't solve the problem since I can't distinguish kind, but it's interesting.